# Create a Tree View in Drupal 7.2

Tags: drupal-7, treeview

I am trying to create a tree view in Drupal 7.2. I've scoured the internet and I found something about adding a view but I do not see anyway to create or add a view. When I go to add content there isn't an option to incorporate the tree view module. I have checked to make sure I have all the modules required installed and enabled. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The views option is in the Structure menu, you can simply type "yourSite/admin/structure/views" . If even though you don't see it, double check that you have installed the Views module.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  views tree module for that

Please find below the project link

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree